# Can't rename Google Drive files with nodeJs library

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm unable to rename files in Google Drive in a NodeJs app. I'm using:

- googleapi nodeJs library v. `20.1.0`.
- node v. `8.1.4`

The app is handling requests for files fine, and it is able to duplicate files. However, when updating them, the new `name` is never applied.

I do get as a response the file resource, which would entail that [the request was successful](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update).

I'm doing this:

```
const google = require( 'googleapis' );
let googleService = google.drive( 'v3' );

let params = {
  auth: testedAndValidOAuth,
  fileId: validFileId,
  uploadType: 'multipart',
  name: "some name 2"
};

googleService.files.update( params, ( err, response ) => console.log(response));
```

For the property `uploadType` I've tried with and without it, with all the available options: `resumable`, `multipart`, and `media`. When trying `media` I got the following error:

```
Error: The API returned an error: Error: Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/xxxfileIdxxx?uploadType=media&name=some+name+2
```

I've tried to edit manually the link in the library and the error went away, but unfortunately the name did not change.

Looking in the library I've noticed that the `name` param is not mentioned:

```
@param {object} params Parameters for request
@param {string=} params.addParents A comma-separated list of parent IDs to add.
@param {string} params.fileId The ID of the file.
@param {boolean=} params.keepRevisionForever Whether to set the 'keepForever' field in the new head revision. This is only applicable to files with binary content in Drive.
@param {string=} params.ocrLanguage A language hint for OCR processing during image import (ISO 639-1 code).
@param {string=} params.removeParents A comma-separated list of parent IDs to remove.
@param {boolean=} params.supportsTeamDrives Whether the requesting application supports Team Drives.
@param {boolean=} params.useContentAsIndexableText Whether to use the uploaded content as indexable text.
@param  {object} params.resource Media resource metadata
@param {object} params.media Media object
@param {string} params.media.mimeType Media mime-type
@param {string|object} params.media.body Media body contents
@param {object} [options] Optionally override request options, such as `url`, `method`, and `encoding`.
@param {callback} callback The callback that handles the response.
```

So I'm wondering, am I doing something wrong, is this intended, meaning that we can't edit file names, or is it a bug in the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your new name in `params.media.body`, eg

```
params.resource = {name: "newname"}
```

corrected as per comment

Comment: Almost! Turns out it has to be set via `params.resource = { name: "newname"}`. I must add that the docs are pretty obscure on this... If you can update the answer I'll accept it :-)

Comment: agree docs are awful. I think the libraries are auto-generated or at least generic to all Google services so documentation and behaviour is often lacking